# Getting minimum number of vertices in graph (tree) so that every edge has at least one chosen vertice

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have this problem, I want to find the smallest array of vertices so that every edge is connected to at least one of those vertices stored in the array.

So in this graph we would for example choose vertices A and D because every edge of the graph is connected either to the A or D (and there can not be found a smaller group of vertices).

Other valid groups of vertices - D and B, A and C.

[image: Example of graph]

Comment: You are looking for the Minimum Vertex Cover, well known NP complete problem

Comment: Thank you buddy, you really helped me :)

Comment: You might also want to look into what's known about approximation, which i is not much. See for example https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~ac/Teach/CS105-Winter05/Notes/wan-ba-scribe.pdf